# Adding an additional conditional with a swtich

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a text game that consists of 4 rooms.  The rooms are laid out like a box divided into 4 parts (NW, NE, SE, SW).  You would travel the rooms starting in the NW room and go clockwise ending in the SW room.

Anyway, I have the basic movements contained in a switch:

```
switch (input) {

case "help":
    $("#messageHelp").properDisplay();

break;

  case "take sword":
if (currentRoom == "nwRoom") {
  $("<p>You picked up a sword.</p>").properDisplay();

} else {
  $("<p>The sword is not here.</p>").properDisplay();

}
break;

case "go east":
    if (currentRoom == "nwRoom") {
        currentRoom = "neRoom";
        $("<p>You are now in the North East Room.</p>").properDisplay();

    } else {
        $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();

    }
    break;

case "go west":
    if (currentRoom == "neRoom") {
        currentRoom = "nwRoom";
        $("<p>You are now in the North West Room.</p>").properDisplay();

    } else {
        $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();

    }
    break;

case "go south":
    if (currentRoom == "neRoom") {
        currentRoom = "seRoom";
        $("<p>You are now in the South East Room.</p>").properDisplay();

    } else {
        $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();

    }
    break;

case "go north":
    if (currentRoom == "seRoom") {
        currentRoom = "neRoom";
        $("<p>You are now in the North East Room.</p>").properDisplay();

    } else {
        $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();

    }
    break;
```

Here's my question - The direction of WEST needs to be duplicated because you should be able to travel east/west in the upper rooms as well as the lower rooms.  How do I do that?  I originally thought of an OR boolean:

`if (currentRoom == "swRoom" || "nwRoom")`

But then the remaining code would make no sense.  I can't duplicate the entire statement because of the break the first time it's used.  I'd like to stick with using a SWITCH for the majority of the code if possible because this is so much cleaner than a massive amount of if else statements.

Ultimately, I want to continue to use this to grow it into a larger game, but am using these 4 rooms to teach myself the basics.

Thanks!

Comment: Id suggest a completely different approach, make objects to represent each of your rooms, then each room can know what other rooms its connected to

Comment: this would include being able to do up down, cupboard to narnia, teleporters, etc

Comment: @KeithNicholas - I have a basic understanding of objects and was going in that direction before I moved to the switch.  Could you show me an example of how you would create the object so that you could move in multiple directions?

I'm guessing something like:

    var seRoom = {
      door1: "nwRoom"
      door2: "swRoom"
    };

Or something along those lines?  My question would be could I duplicate the same commands (door1, door2) in other objects but with different results?  (ie.  seRoom.door1  vs nwRoom.door1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Keith Nicholas' idea, you can represent the rooms as a single object, something like this:

```
var rooms = {
  northWest: {
    name: "North East",
    hasSword: true,
    paths: {
      east: "northEast",
      south: "southWest"
    }
  },
  northEast: {
    name: "North East",
    paths: {
      west: "northWest",
      south: "southEast"
    }
  },
  southWest: {
    name: "South West",
    paths: {
      east: "southEast",
      north: "northWest"
    }
  },
  southEast: {
    name: "South East",
    paths: {
      west: "southWest",
      north: "northEast"
    }
  },
};
```

Set your `currentRoom` when your game starts

```
var currentRoom = rooms["northWest"];
```

Since the functionality between travelling in either direction is relatively similar, you want to reuse as much code as possible. You could create a travel function, something like this:

```
var travel = function(direction) {
  var newRoom = rooms[currentRoom.paths[direction]];
  if(!newRoom) {
    $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();
  }
  else {
    currentRoom = newRoom;
    $("<p>You are now in the " + currentRoom.name + " Room.</p>").properDisplay();
  }
};
```

This function will take a string direction like "east" or "west". The first variable assignment will attempt to get a room from the object we've created above. So say for example we're in the north west room, and the direction input is east. This line will effectively do this

```
currentRoom.paths["east"]
```

Since we're in the north west room, this will return that string:

```
northWest: {
  name: "North East",
  paths: {
    east: "northEast", // This string will be returned.
    south: "southWest"
  }
}
```

With this string we can now get the new room we moved to using:

```
rooms["northEast"]
```

So putting it all together is

```
rooms[currentRoom.paths[direction]];
```

Now if this happens to return nothing, ie. the path with the direction "east" doesn't exist in the currentRoom, our variable will be `undefined` which will evaluate to `false`.

This is important for the next step because it allows us to check if we were able to a new room. A `false` evaluation means we weren't and that's what we tell the player.

If there is a room returned, we set that to be the current room. Display the name of the room, and we're done. You can then run this travel function from inside your switch statement:

```
var receiveInput = function(input) {
  switch(input) {
    case "help":
      $("#messageHelp").properDisplay();
      break;
    case "take sword":
      takeSword();
      break;
    case "go east":
      travel("east");
      break;
    case "go west":
      travel("west");
      break;
    case "go north":
      travel("north");
      break;
    case "go south":
      travel("south");
      break;
  }
}
```

Bonus take sword function:

```
var takeSword = function() {
  if(currentRoom.hasSword) {
    $("<p>You picked up a sword.</p>").properDisplay();
  }
  else {
    $("<p>The sword is not here.</p>").properDisplay();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @JamesHay, that makes a lot more sense to my noob brain.  I didn't realize that objects could be so involved.  My original thinking was to make each room an object but I couldn't translate the concept into a functioning model in the game.  I appreciate your detailed answer.  It really helps me use and learn from it.  Many thanks!

Comment: No problem. There are infinite ways something like this can be modelled, so this is just my take on it. One of the key things to take from my answer is to try and abstract common functionality whereever you can.

Comment: agreed.  This was originally one huge if else statement.  From there, I've started trying to learn new ideas to make it tighter and more efficient.  All the StackO folks have been mega helpful getting me from one stage to the next.

Comment: Hey @JamesHay, I finally read through everything and implemented your code.  When I do, nothing returns at the prompt.  ie.  Regardless of what I type, nothing happens.  No errors are kicking out on Chrome Console.  Here's the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/megler/wobvsdf9/

I'm not testing on fiddle, but it was the easiest way to show how I structured everything.

Comment: @megler A number of issues in you're code, I've updated your fiddle with a [working version](https://jsfiddle.net/wobvsdf9/4/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to emulate a data structure by using conditionals. Why not just use a [graph](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/graph/linked/)?

Here's how you *could* structure a Room object:

```
var Room = function(name, treasure) {
    this.name = name;
    this.treasure = treasure;
    this.exit = {
        north: null,
        south: null,
        east: null,
        west: null
    };

    this.addAdjacentRoom = function(Room, location) {
        var oppositeDirection = {
            north: "south",
            south: "north",
            east: "west",
            west: "east"
        }
        if (location in exits) {
            this.exit[location] = Room;
            Room.exit[oppositeDirection[location]] = this;
        }       
    };
};
```

Now let's add something to hold all these rooms:

```
var Dungeon = function(Room) {
    this.currentRoom = Room;
    this.changeRoom = function(direction) {
        var nextRoom = this.currentRoom.exit[direction];
        if (nextRoom) {
            $("<p>You are now in the " + nextRoom.name +" Room.</p>").properDisplay();
            this.currentRoom = nextRoom;
        } else {
            $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();
        }
    };
    this.pickUpTreasure = function() {
        var treasure = this.currentRoom.treasure;
        if (treasure) {
            $("<p>You picked up a " + treasure + ".</p>").properDisplay();
        } else {
            $("<p>There is no treasure here.</p>").properDisplay();
        }
    };
};
```

Now you can start building your dungeon and going on your adventure!

```
var entrance = new Room("entrance");
var lobby = new Room("lobby");
// this room has treasure!
var treasureCave = new Room("treasure cave", "magical sword of destiny");
var prison = new Room("prison");

entrance.addAdjacentRoom(lobby, "west");
lobby.addAddAdjacentRoom(treasureCave, "north");
lobby.addAddAdjacentRoom(prison, "south");

var myDungeon = new Dungeon(entrance);

myDungeon.changeRoom("west");
myDungeon.changeRoom("north");
myDungeon.pickUpTreasure();
```

Comment: Oh wow, @Jonathan, that's WAY more than my little weenie object!  I understand what this does, but I'm going to have to really look at this awhile to figure out why it does what it does.  I don't quite get each of the functions.  I'll work on it.  Thanks!

Comment: @megler try looking up some articles on javascript classes. [This one's a bit old](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/), but it's pretty readable, and you might find it helpful. Javascript's actually changing now, and now you can [straight-up define classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will definitely do that.  I decided to try this small game to better learn some JS concepts.  It was a good decision.  I have learned SO much more doing this than just trying to learn abstract concepts.  Thanks again for the help!